# How do I disable my second option if the first is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have 10 dropdowns select field in **five rows**! If someone select something from the first or second select, than I want to **disable** the other one in the **same row** (do not disappear only disable)!

When I select the **Enable** value than the disabled select should be enabled!

Sorry for my english, i hope you understand my problem!
Thank you in advance!!

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>
        First select
      </th>
      <th>
        Second select
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>    
</table>
```

[Click Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nzlorca/51fevoam/)

Comment: Any how you did it any try in jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use this snippet:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('select').not(this).prop('disabled', this.value !== "enable")
});
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51fevoam/3/)

Comment: That is a cool peice of code tbh. Didn't know about the .not(this)

Comment: @Grimbode that's used when you are in a context of parent but you want to exclude the current selector it from the list.

Answer (score 1):

This will help:

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
   $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").find("select").attr("disabled",true);
   if($(this).val()=="enable") {          
      $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").find("select").attr("disabled",false);
   }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51fevoam/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    if($(this).val()!='enable') {
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('select').prop('disabled',true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('select').prop('disabled',false);
    }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/51fevoam/8/

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the answer, what is you are looking for. I think you can 
simplify more. But anyhow you got the idea.

```
HTML - 
<table id='myTable'>
   <tr>
      <th>
        First select
      </th>
      <th>
        Second select
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="enable">Enable</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>    
</table>

Javascript -     
    var items = $('#myTable select').on('change', function() {
            var index = items.index(this);
            var selectArray = $('select');
            if(index === 0 || index === 2 || index === 4 || index === 6 || index === 8) {
                console.log(index);
                $(selectArray[index + 1]).attr('disabled', true);
            } else if (index === 1 || index === 3 || index === 5 || index === 7 || index === 9) {
                console.log(index);
                $(selectArray[index - 1]).attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
```

JSFiddle Link - https://jsfiddle.net/nzlorca/51fevoam/

Comment: Yes it's good, but I need a refresh to re-enabled the disabled select!